# Paginação utilizando demoiselle 2.5.0

Tags: java, paginação, demoiselle

Iniciei hoje os testes no sistema com a versão mais atual do demoiselle (2.5), porem, não está mais funcionando a paginação.

Ao entrar na página o conteúdo é listado, mas no momento em que trocar de página, já não aparece mais nada.

Anteriormente eu estava utilizando a versão 2.4.2.

Vale ressaltar que eu atualizei também para o PrimeFaces 5.2, porem, quando identifiquei o erro voltei para a versão 5.0 do PrimeFaces que funcionava anteriormente, mas mesmo assim não funcionou mais a paginação.

Aguem está passando por isto e sabe como resolver?

Exemplo de código:

```
private LazyDataModel<Cliente> dataModel;

@Override
public LazyDataModel<Cliente> getDataModel() {
    if (dataModel == null) {
        dataModel = new LazyDataModel<Cliente>() {
            @Override
            public List<Cliente> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
                Pagination pagination = getPagination();
                pagination.setPageSize(pageSize);
                pagination.setFirstResult(first);

                List<Cliente> itemsList = handleResultList();

                dataModel.setRowCount(pagination.getTotalResults());

                return itemsList;
            }
        };
    }
    return dataModel;
}

@Override
protected List<Cliente> handleResultList() {
    if(search.isAll()){
        return this.clienteBC.findFastByExample(null);
    }
    Cliente bean = new Cliente();
    bean.setParticipante(search.getBean());
    return this.clienteBC.findFastByExample(bean);
}
```

O meu xhtml está da seguinte forma:

```
   <p:dataTable id="list" var="bean" value="#{clienteListMB.dataModel}" lazy="true" paginator="true" 
                 first="${messages['page.first']}" rows="${messages['page.rows']}"
                 pageLinks="${messages['page.max.links']}">
        <p:column style="width: 8%; text-align: left;" sortBy="#{bean.id}">
            <f:facet name="header">${messages['participante.label.id']}</f:facet>
            <h:commandLink action="#{clienteListMB.getNextView}" actionListener="#{clienteListMB.clear}">
                <h:outputText value="#{bean.id}" />
                <f:param name="cli_id" value="#{bean.id}" />
                <f:param name="part_id" value="#{bean.participante.id}" />
                <f:param name="tipo_cad" value="#{2}" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="width: 15%; text-align: left;" sortBy="#{bean.participante.codigo}">
            <f:facet name="header">${messages['participante.label.codigo']}</f:facet>
            <h:commandLink action="#{clienteListMB.getNextView}" actionListener="#{clienteListMB.clear}">
                <h:outputText value="#{bean.participante.codigo}" />
                <f:param name="cli_id" value="#{bean.id}" />
                <f:param name="part_id" value="#{bean.participante.id}" />
                <f:param name="tipo_cad" value="#{2}" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="width: 50%; text-align: left;" sortBy="#{bean.participante.nome}">
            <f:facet name="header">${messages['participante.label.nome']}</f:facet>
            <h:commandLink action="#{clienteListMB.getNextView}" actionListener="#{clienteListMB.clear}">
                <h:outputText value="#{bean.participante.nome}" />
                <f:param name="cli_id" value="#{bean.id}" />
                <f:param name="part_id" value="#{bean.participante.id}" />
                <f:param name="tipo_cad" value="#{2}" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="width: 15%; text-align: left;">
            <f:facet name="header">${messages['participante.label.doc']}</f:facet>
            <h:commandLink action="#{clienteListMB.getNextView}" actionListener="#{clienteListMB.clear}">
                <!--NOVO METODO DE MOSTRAR O DOCUMENTO OU O ID ESTRANGEIRO, DESSA 
                FORMA DISPENSA O USO DE UM OUTPUTTEXT COM REDERED-->
                <h:outputText value="#{bean.participante.documento}#{bean.participante.idEstrangeiro}" />
                <f:param name="cli_id" value="#{bean.id}" />
                <f:param name="part_id" value="#{bean.participante.id}" />
                <f:param name="tipo_cad" value="#{2}" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="width: 15%; text-align: left;" sortBy="#{bean.participante.fone}">
            <f:facet name="header">${messages['participante.label.fone']}</f:facet>
            <h:commandLink action="#{clienteListMB.getNextView}" actionListener="#{clienteListMB.clear}">
                <h:outputText value="#{bean.participante.fone}" />
                <f:param name="cli_id" value="#{bean.id}" />
                <f:param name="part_id" value="#{bean.participante.id}" />
                <f:param name="tipo_cad" value="#{2}" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="width:10%; text-align: center;">
            <f:facet name="header">${messages['label.actions']}</f:facet>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" role="group">
                <h:commandLink action="#{clienteListMB.getNextView}" actionListener="#{clienteListMB.clear}" title="${messages['button.edit']}" class="btn btn-white">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"/>
                    <f:param name="cli_id" value="#{bean.id}" />
                    <f:param name="part_id" value="#{bean.participante.id}" />
                    <f:param name="tipo_cad" value="#{2}" />
                </h:commandLink>   
            </div>                    
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foi constatado um defeito nessa funcionalidade, até a versão 2.4.2 a implementação da classe PaginationContext tinha escopo de sessão e mudou para request mas isso está gerando esse problema.

Agradecemos se puder registrar isso no nosso sistema de BugTrack (http://tracker.frameworkdemoiselle.gov.br)

Comment: Certo. Vou registrar sim! Obrigado pela resposta!